# Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /drawable/fa_diesis.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android-studio, canvas, bitmap, drawable

I'm new in Android Development and i'm facing with this issue. 
I would like to insert a png image on the screen using the *drawBitmap()* function of *Canvas*. But when i try to decode such image i get this error:

**Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException:** /drawable/fa_diesis.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err: **java.lang.NullPointerException:** Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference

Here's the following code:

```
 private void drawImage(float x, float y){
            File file = new File("drawable/fa_diesis.png");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            Rect source = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
            Rect bitmapRect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, new Paint());
    }
```

In **drawable** folder i have this structure:
[res folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ5qy.png)
.I noticed that the photo I would like to use has the tag (androidTest), maybe it should not have it.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Your path is relative. Try using an absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try to re copy paste your image. the file should be only the name without androidTest. when adding image, make sure the directory is going to \app\src\main\res\drawable

then remove file class and the variable also change following code to access your image in drawable to be bitmap

> Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

to be

> Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fa_diesis);

the method

```
private void drawImage(float x, float y) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fa_diesis);
        Rect source = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        Rect bitmapRect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, new Paint());
}
```

hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved adding the desired image again,
maybe I added it badly. Now there is no longer "androidtest" slogan next to the image. I also replaced *decodeFile* with *decodeResource* function.

Thank you very much!

Comment: did my answer help you?

Comment: Yes, using decodeFile function i wasn't able to use properly the image, so i changed that funciton whit decodeResource as you suggested

Comment: Sorry I didn't know I'm new in SO. Bye.